# When is XML parsing finished in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, iphone

I am using ordinary XML parser and store the values of XML in a dictionary.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"CountryId"]){
        currentTweet.content = currentNodeContent;
        [data setObject:currentTweet.content forKey:@"CountryId"];
        //NSLog(@"currentNode is %@",currentNodeContent);
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"CountryName"]){
        currentTweet.createdAt = currentNodeContent;
        [data setObject:currentTweet.createdAt forKey:@"CountryName"];
        //NSLog(@"currentNode is countnry Name %@",currentNodeContent);
    }

    /*if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Country"]){
        [tweets addObject:currentTweet];

        tweet *current       = [tweets objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"value of current is %@",current.content);
        NSLog(@"value of Country tweet is %@",current.createdAt);
        [currentTweet release];
         currentTweet = nil;
        [currentNodeContent release];
         currentNodeContent = nil;
    }*/
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

I want to know about some method which tell me when XML data is completely read and stored in an array. I use these methods with web delegate methods because i read data from soap in view did load finishing i pass the XML to XML parser like this:

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSLog(@"recived data %@",webData);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] 
                initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] 
                length:[webData length] 
                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //---shows the XML---
    NSLog(@"%@",theXML);
    [theXML release];    


    if( xmlParser )
    {
        [xmlParser release];
    }

    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
    //[xmlParser setDelegate: self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
    [xmlParser parse];

    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [parserDidEndDocument:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate)

Comment: `- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{

 NSLog(@"parserDidEndDocument");

}`

Comment: i have write the function at the end but it called first here is the oput put of the function:

Comment: [Session started at 2011-02-25 09:53:22 +0500.]
2011-02-25 09:53:24.616 TwitterDemo[1327:207] parserDidEndDocument
2011-02-25 09:53:24.617 TwitterDemo[1327:207] Dato: Sun May 25 09:52:11 +0000 2008 med innhold Webkit/Chrome developer tools presentation from Google i/o: http://t.co/4kpLg8N
2011-02-25 09:53:24.618 TwitterDemo[1327:207] Dato: Sun May 25

Comment: parserDidEnd Document called on first